Why doesn't 5 V PWM (50% duty cycle) burn my 2.5 V rated LED?
I wanted to light up an LED with max voltage rating of 2.5 V. The power supply is 5 V. I used PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) to directly use 5 V output to 2.5 V LED.
I set PWM frequency to 100 Hz (means 100 cycles in a second).
Duty cycle is set to 50%. Means the signal would be full 5 V 50% of the time in a single cycle and 0 V for the remaining time.
I executed the code and the LED lit up successfully.
Question: Shouldn't the LED be burnt as it received 5 V (even if it was for half of the time)?

use a resistor instead

Your question title and question text has two different questions...

Are you sure 5v was delivered to the LED? (did you measure it with an oscilloscope?)... or did it's current consumption rise significantly and therefore the supplied voltage dropped? Many I/O pins are typically only able to deliver ~20mA without collapsing / failing (possibly 50mA for a particularly strong device)!

The LED should burn out, but it seems your MCU or whatever chip that is outputing the PWM has so large source impedance that it can't burn the LED.
MCU IO pins and other IO pins from chips are rather weak, they can only drive some 20mA as per the specs and may damage at 40 or 50mA.
They are not intended to drive LED without series resitance.
So your LED never received 5V from a 5V MCU.

Thanks for answer. Just want to provide some additional information. The led became brighter if i increased the duty cycle from 50 to 60%. Does this means the applied voltage is also varying with this?

A LED is a Diode which behaves (simplified) as an open circuit for V < Vth and as a short circuit for V > Vth. Vth denotes the threshold voltage which, in your case, is 2.5 V.
If the LED is on, we assume it has a voltage drop of Vth. If your LED is powered from 5 V, this means we have to drop the remaining 2.5 V over something else like a resistor. You can calculate the resistor value needed as R = (5 V - Vth) / Imax
where Imax is the maximal current allowed to flow through your LED. If you don't have the calculated resistor value, use the next bigger resistor you have.
You can then connect this resistor in series with your LED and your LED will work.

Thanks for the answer but i want to know what cause the led to not burn even though 5v was applied half of the duty cycle.

@Pratham If you measure it with your oscilloscope, you will find that 5 V was never supplied to it. Your MCU may be permanently damaged from the abuse though.

@Pratham Under the assumption that your MCU can supply enough current (which is not the case), your LED will die due to an overcurrent. In reality, you basically create a short circuit to ground on the MCUs pin.
Keep in mind that, in contrast to e.g. resistors, LEDs are highly non-linear elements.
